# Visual Studio 2019: Run React JS on a local network

Tags: c#, node.js, reactjs, api, visual-studio-2019

I was wondering if it is possible to run my Reactjs project with API on local network. BTW I'm using visual studio not visual studio code. If it's not possible do you have any recommendation to run it while the project is on development? Sorry for noob question. Thank you so much any recommendation is acceptable.

Comment: Deploy it to IIS, configure firewall and that's it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I'm going to look for deployment tutorial.